# how to filter for string contained in pagePath in google analytics

Tags: filter, google-analytics

I am using google analytics query explorer http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/ to fetch all pagepath given by the dimension 'ga:pagePath' containing the word 'paypal'. How to create a filtering condition for this? I want to keep only those rows containing the word 'paypal'

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [API Reference - Filters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters). If you scroll down a bit you see the **Dimension Filters** chart.

It sounds like you could use one of the following:

1. Contains substring using the operator **=@**

   - Example: Aggregate metrics where the city contains York: filters=ga:city%3D@York
2. Contains a match for the regular expression using the operator **=~**

   - Aggregate metrics where the city starts with New:
     filters=ga:city%3D~%5ENew.*
     (%5E is the URL encoded from of the ^ character that anchors a pattern to the beginning of the string.)

If you have any questions, just let me know.

Comment: I tried using: 'ga:pagePath%3D@paypal' but the I got the following error: Ack! There was an error (400)Invalid value 'ga:pagePath%3D@paypal' for filters parameter.

Comment: When you are using the Query Explorer you should just use the standard operator, =@, not the URL encoded version of the operator.